# save webview state in fragment while changing different fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-service

I try much different code on google but none of that work for me.
so I have 2 fragments (with webview), 1st fragment goes to youtube.com and 2nd fragment goes to google.com

so when my app start it start with 1st fragment , and then when I go to 2nd fragment and comes back to 1st it reloads it again  , but I want it should save its state, and never reloads on changing fragment , but fragment(webview) should get refresh when user close the app and start again .just using navigation drawer to switch between fragment

**here is my code for 1st fragment**

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * created ny anshul 
 */
public class BlankFragment12 extends Fragment {

    public Handler h;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Bundle webViewBundle;
    public AdView adView;
    public WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);

    }
    public BlankFragment12() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view
                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment12, container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);

        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.hu);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://youtube.com/");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad9View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad10View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad13View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad14View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad11View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad12View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn1);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn2);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn3);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn4);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn5);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad103);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn13);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn23);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn33);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }



            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

**code for 2nd fragment**

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * created by anshul
 */
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {
public  Bundle webViewBundle;
    public Handler h;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public AdView adView;
    public WebView mWebView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);



        }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);

    }


    public BlankFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        setRetainInstance(true);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view
                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment3, container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        progressBar.setProgress(1);






        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.hu);


        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");



        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad9View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad10View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad11View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad12View);

        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad13View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad14View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn1);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn2);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn3);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn4);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn5);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad103);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn13);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn23);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn33);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }

        });    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }



            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return view;    }
}
```

**onNavigationItemSelected code**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            BlankFragment4 blankFragment4 = new BlankFragment4();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment4).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.i) {
            BlankFragment7 blankFragment7 = new BlankFragment7();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment7).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.sav) {
            BlankFragment12 blankFragment12 = new BlankFragment12();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment12).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.home) {
            BlankFragment2 blankFragment2 = new BlankFragment2();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment2).commit();
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
               BlankFragment3 blankFragment3 = new BlankFragment3();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment3).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            BlankFragment9 blankFragment9 = new BlankFragment9();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment9).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.coll) {
            BlankFragment11 blankFragment11 = new BlankFragment11();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment11).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.bf13) {
            BlankFragment13 blankFragment13 = new BlankFragment13();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment13).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.bf14) {
            BlankFragment14 blankFragment14 = new BlankFragment14();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment14).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.bf15) {
            BlankFragment15 blankFragment15 = new BlankFragment15();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment15).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.fav) {
            BlankFragment10 blankFragment10 = new BlankFragment10();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment10).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            BlankFragment8 blankFragment8 = new BlankFragment8();
            FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager  .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou, blankFragment8).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.da) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=hoogle")));
        }
        else if (id == R.id.d) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hoogle.news2")));
        }
        else if (id == R.id.funny) {
            BlankFragment6 blankFragment6 = new BlankFragment6();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.oou,blankFragment6).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

***extra suggestion for making webview more smooth/better are welcome***

Comment: How are you adding/replacing fragment?

Comment: both fragment are listed on navigation drawer. just using navigation drawer to switch between fragment

Comment: you should be handling `onNavigationItemSelected` method. Show its code

Comment: @RahulKhurana  see i posted onNavigationSelected code

Comment: in the onNavigationItemSelected method, you're using `replace` which removes your previous fragment when you navigate to another

Comment: @RahulKhurana so how to solve it ??

Comment: Use `add` instead of `replace`. Also pass fragment name in `addToBackStack` method. After this, you need to add BackGround color as white and make clickable true in all fragments parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create new instance of fragment and replace the old one, so the old one is destroyed. You should use findFragmentByTag add/detach/show/hide methods to keep fragment instances alive

Every time you detach fragment your view is destroyed. So, onCreateView called every time you attach your fragment and loadUrl called every time you return to your fragment

try this in your onCreateView

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
} else {
   webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: @anshul you should use both. replace destroys fragment so onSaveInstaneState will not be called, so you should only use add, detach and findFragmentByTag methods to manage your fragment if you want to save fragment instance. And beside that you should use code that i posted in onCreateView

Comment: hi could you answer these question ??     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267166/share-via-whatsapp-in-web-view                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271124/popup-inside-webview-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can add fragments in your transaction and show only 1st one, hide the others.
Firstly you will have to create instances of Fragments :

```
private FragmentA fragmentA;
private FragmentB fragmentB;`
```

In `onCreate` of your activity :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentA).
                show(fragmentA).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentB).
                hide(fragmentB).commit();
```

And now its time to change fragments you can use this code :

```
  public void replaceFragment(int position) {
        Fragment frag;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if (!(fragmentToOpen instanceof FragmentA)){
                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragmentToOpen)
                      .show(fragmentA).commit();
                }
                fragmentToOpen = fragmentA;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (!(fragmentToOpen instanceof FragmentB)){                    
                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragmentToOpen)
                      .show(fragmentB).commit();
                }
                fragmentToOpen = fragmentB;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi could you answer these question ??     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267166/share-via-whatsapp-in-web-view                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271124/popup-inside-webview-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Make FragmentManager global and try the below code

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction=  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFr
            transaction.replace( R.id.contain, R.id.oou,"FragmentOne");
            transaction.addToBackStack( null);
            transaction.commit();
}
```

here FragmentOne is the tag name which will be declare in your BlankFragment.

Comment: hi could you answer these question ??     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267166/share-via-whatsapp-in-web-view                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271124/popup-inside-webview-in-android-studio